# Delete specific word from table column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have ONE column in MySQl table which contains words in this format:

Name - Name2 - Name3

and I'd like to delete Name2, and to leave just Name - Name3

So I just need to delete middle word, and not the entire column! The middle word is always the same.

Is that possible?

Comment: Hi, you probably tried something, don't be shy, and show it !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update your_table
set your_column = concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column, '-', 1), '-',
                         SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column, '-', -1))
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/2721)
[substring-index doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Comment: So let me be more specific; 
Inside COL 1, there is

Cat - Grey - small 
Cat - Grey - middle 
Cat - Grey - big 
Dog - Grey - big 


I need to delete Grey in all of the entries.. 

Think i cannot do this with substring, If I got it right.. 

Thanks for your time!

Comment: That is a totally different question. If you just want to remove something then do `update table set col = replace(col, 'Grey', '')`

Comment: You have a big problem with your database design.  Those should be separate columns.  Fix it now, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `REPLACE`.

```
UPDATE table SET column=REPLACE(column,'Yourstring','')
```

Suppose I have a table name car, and inside this table, there is a column called version. In this version, there are few data which has the string 'Auto', and I want to remove this.

GT 1.4 Turbo MultiAir 2d Auto -> GT 1.4 Turbo MultiAir 2d

So, the simple solution will be:

```
UPDATE cars SET version=REPLACE(version,'Auto','')
```

It will work for every occurrence.